# how to select data between dates using php mysql with conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

I have given the query like this:

```
$sql12 = "select roomno from guestrocordtransac where checkin between '".$format_checkin."' and '".$format_checkout."' and roomtype='".$roomtype."'";
```

table:**guestrocordtransac**

```
id roomno roomtype  checkin          checkout

1   101    Seashell 2015-05-20       2015-05-28

2   202    Seashore  2015-05-15      2015-05-30
```

table2:**roominfo**

```
id  roomno  roomtype 

 1   101    Seashell 

 2   102    Seashell 

 3   201    Seashore

 4  202    Seashore
```

when i  tried using the query in php i will be getting a null value...I dont know what happened with the query..

When tried in mysql i'm getting a record less

Comment: between works between 2 values, not 3. This isn't a club sandwich ;-)

Comment: then how to use my condition

Comment: you could use a sub-query, so use brackets `(first query)`.

Comment: Try the *Try this* answer below then.

Comment: Are you sure you were getting values within variables

Comment: What's the actual value of `$sql12`? (`echo $sql12`)

Comment: where is `roominfo` in query..?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No problem with the third argument, the precedence works well here.

Comment: @HonzaHaering I stand corrected.

Comment: @user3114964 Which MySQL API are you using to connect with?

Comment: yeah...i'm sure about it..

Comment: code:    
$sql12 = "select roomno from guestrocordtransac where checkin >= '".$format_checkin."' and checkin <= '".$format_checkout."' and roomtype='".$roomtype."'";
    $retval12 = mysql_query( $sql12, $conn );
  if(mysql_num_rows($retval12)== 0){echo"hiiiii if part";
   $sql11 = "select room_no from roominfo where roomtype='".$roomtype."'"; $retval11 = mysql_query( $sql11, $conn );
 $character = implode(",", $rmn11);
   while($row11 = mysql_fetch_array($retval11,MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {?> 
  <option value="<?php echo $row11['room_no']?>"><?php echo $row11['room_no']."bbbbbbb";?></option>
 <?php}}

Comment: Edit the question, this is unreadable.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You now have enough to debug your code with.

Comment: what the %@&* is going on with these reviewers?????????????? [that code of yours in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324333/how-to-select-data-between-dates-using-php-mysql-with-conditions#comment48743967_30324333) **DOES NOT BELONG THERE** - Flag declined... a big *you know what*.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$sql12 = "select roomno from guestrocordtransac where checkin >= '".$format_checkin."' and checkin <= '".$format_checkout."' and roomtype='".$roomtype."'";
```

Comment: *try this...* - why? and why is their query failing now?

Comment: @Fred-ii- this query should work. because i always use this type of query when ever i have to take data between 2 dates.

Comment: @noddy OP seems to have vanished. That's not my downvote by the way. OP has been given methods to check for errors and then they were gone.

Comment: I never said it didn't or wouldn't work. That should be aimed at @user3114964 who has disappeared and left everyone *high and dry*. Voted to close the question.